# Problem with CUDA program

Tags: c++, c, cuda

Here's my code:

```
#include <vector_types.h>
#define sizeOfGrid   5
__global__ void stuff( float3 *grid ) {
    grid[0].x = 0.4f; //PROBLEM HERE?!
}
int main( void ) {
    float3 *grid[sizeOfGrid];
    float3 *dev_grid;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_grid, sizeOfGrid*sizeof(float3)));
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfGrid; i++)
    {
        grid[i] = new float3();
        grid[i]->x = 1.3f;
        grid[i]->y = 1.3f;
        grid[i]->z = 1.3f;
    }


    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(dev_grid, grid, sizeOfGrid * sizeof(float3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    stuff<<<sizeOfGrid, 1>>> (dev_grid);
    cudaMemcpy(grid, dev_grid, sizeOfGrid*sizeof(float3), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(dev_grid);
}
```

Right now it's just a test program, not meant to do anything useful. Compiles and runs fine, but it doesn't seem to be setting grid[0] correctly. Is it because I'm setting the grid[0] wrong in the device code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
float3 *grid[sizeOfGrid];
```

you are allocating an array of pointers to float3, not an array of float3.
You should declare

```
float3 grid[sizeOfGrid];
```

and use . instead of ->, or

```
float3 *grid;
```

and use malloc and free.

Comment: thanks! worked! not sure if you were the same guy as in the IRC chat room. but thanks to both of you if you aren't. :D